# Preact doesn't show the value inside the list tag

Tags: preact

In this Preact example, I'm trying to map over **items** array and print the result inside the **li** tag.
But the li is always empty with no error in console.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import { h } from '../preact.js'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks'

function mySeachList ({
  items
}) {
  console.log(items)
  const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState(items)

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchList(items)
  }, [])

  return h('ul.test-class', searchList.map((item, index) => {
    h('li', null, item.keywords)
  }))
}

export default mySeachList
```

Comment: probably `return h('ul.test-class', searchList.map` should be `return h('ul',{ class: 'test-class'}, searchList.map`

Comment: Yes, that was it. I found the solution a couple of days ago. But thanks for your help.